# CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 218 consistency errors in table 'MyDatabase' (object ID 1509580416)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

My database was unexpectedly went into suspect mode. After analyzing I found that this is because of the log issue. So, I rebuild the log once again. After rebuilding the log file, I ran the SQL command `DBCC CHECKDB(MYDATATBASE)`.

It throws some errors so I tried to repair the database by using the following command

```
DBCC CHECKDB (MYDATATBASE, REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS) 
WITH NO_INFOMSGS, ALL_ERRORMSGS;
```

The above command executed with the below following errors:

> CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 218 consistency errors in table 'MYDATATBASE' (object ID 1509580416).
>
> CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 1625 consistency errors in database 'CORRESPONDENCE'.

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with **programming** (which *this site* is **all about**), but with DB administration - so it's off-topic here and belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) - voting to move.